# Can not ping docker container from another host which is in the same LAN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, docker

I have two hosts, in the same LAN, both running docker:

- Host A: 172.16.0.113
- Host B: 172.16.0.114

I can ping host A from host B. But, I can not ping a docker container on host A from host B.

I created a docker container running ubuntu, in the docker default network (bridge). The default docker0's IP address is 172.17.0.1. And the IP address of the container (ubuntu) in the host (172.16.0.113) is 172.17.0.2. The command I used is here:

```
sudo docker run --name container01 -it -p 8080:80 ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I can ping container01 from its host, host A; but I can not ping container01 from the other host, host B. Note that I have exposed the port of container01.

I think when I ping container01 from the host B, packets are sent to a container in that host. But I want to know how to connect to host A's container01 from host B.

Comment: Remember that [`ping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) doesn't work over [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)), so exposing port 8080 will not affect whether you can ping another container.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try doing

`sudo docker run --name container01 -it --network=host -p 8080:80 ubuntu /bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers run on private addresses that aren't normally accessible from other hosts. If you have multiple docker hosts, then you should setup [overlay networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/) to place containers on the same private network where they can access each other; this can be done automatically with [swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/).

For reaching containers from outside of docker, you need to publish a port. With `docker run` that's the `-p 8080:80` option that would map the host port 8080 to the container port 80 (you can adjust these port numbers). With a docker-compose.yml, there's a similar `ports` section.

Comment: I have used swarm mode on host A and B. And I created an overlay network named my-multi-host-network. The command is:                           sudo docker service create --name my_web --network my-multi-host-network --publish 8008:80 --replicas 10 nginx   Then it created 10 nginx containers both on host A and B. IP address of my_web.1 is 172.16.1.3.  When I ping 172.16.1.3, I still could not connect the container my_web.1 on host A from host B. So can host B visit container(s) on host A?

Comment: Containers can reach each other using the overlay network, container to container. You do not go from outside host to container directly on the container ip. Instead you access it using the published port on the host. 8008, on either host will round robin route to one of the containers.

Comment: So, if I do not use ping command to test the connectivity,what commands should I use to test the connectivity between container on host A and host B?

Comment: You can ping, but from container to container, not from remote host to container.