# Unable to ping a host from docker container

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I have been working on this for more than a week and unable to find a solution. Desperate for some help

1. I have 2 hosts, host1 and host2.

### Network Details of host 1.

-bash-4.2$ /sbin/ifconfig

docker0:

```
    flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:51ff:fe23:53d7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:51:23:53:d7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 873  bytes 218751 (213.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 532  bytes 86121 (84.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

eth0:

```
    flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet 10.40.89.167  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 10.40.95.255
    inet6 2606:b400:c13:e03:f816:3eff:fe48:f5d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe48:f5d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fa:16:3e:48:0f:5d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 156003879  bytes 37924713148 (35.3 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 17  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8377241  bytes 1139655340 (1.0 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lo:

```
    flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 128401  bytes 29691788 (28.3 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 128401  bytes 29691788 (28.3 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

veth0313598:

```
    flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::88f8:2fff:fe15:e7c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 8a:f8:2f:15:e7:c7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 365  bytes 190333 (185.8 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 884  bytes 191667 (187.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

### Network Details of host2

docker0:

```
    flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    ether 02:42:e6:0d:4c:a6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

eth0:

```
    flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet 10.40.67.187  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 10.40.71.255
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe0b:cdb7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2606:b400:c13:e00:f816:3eff:fe0b:cdb7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether fa:16:3e:0b:cd:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 206797690  bytes 42338336490 (39.4 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6772819  bytes 1007703663 (961.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lo:

```
    flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 133640  bytes 30800694 (29.3 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 133640  bytes 30800694 (29.3 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

***Problem Statement :***

1. I have a docker container in **host1** running Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition. I am able to connect to this database from external world using port mapping 4521 of host to 1521 of container.
2. I am able to ping **host1** from the **Oracle container**

[oracle@b1d3ef32e104 ~]$ ping -c 2 10.40.89.167

```
    PING 10.40.89.167 (10.40.89.167) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.40.89.167: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
    64 bytes from 10.40.89.167: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
    --- 10.40.89.167 ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1043ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.081/0.085/0.090/0.010 ms
```

3. I am able to ping host2 from host1

-bash-4.2$ ping -c 2 10.40.67.187

```
    PING 10.40.67.187 (10.40.67.187) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.40.67.187: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.320 ms
    64 bytes from 10.40.67.187: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.478 ms
    --- 10.40.67.187 ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1005ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.320/0.399/0.478/0.079 ms
```

4. Actual Problem : I am unable to ping **host2** from the **Oracle Container**

[oracle@b1d3ef32e104 ~]$ ping -c 2 10.40.67.187

```
    PING 10.40.67.187 (10.40.67.187) 56(84) bytes of data.
    ^C
    --- 10.40.67.187 ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1023ms
```

I am using the default docker bridge network. firewalld is running on both the hosts with default configuration. host1 has 4521 port open for connecting to the database

Comment: In order to access the same network of your host, your container network shouldn't be `bridge` but `host` instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166716/can-not-ping-docker-container-from-another-host-which-is-in-the-same-lan) question.

Comment: Yes. Host works, but it was working earlier with bridge as well. Something had changed, which the VM administrators are not sure about. However host is not recommended by our organization and cannot do the same unfortunately

Comment: How are you starting your container? Share the full command.

Comment: This is how I created the container  . sudo docker run --name coredb19c -p 4521:1521 -p 5500:5500 -v /scratch/share:/share -v vol-1:/u01/app/oracle/oradata -e ORACLE_SID=COREDB19C -e ORACLE_PDB=PDBCORE19C -e ORACLE_PWD=oracle -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 -d -it banglamon/oracle193db:19.3.0-ee . I start the container with sudo docker start coredb19c